# Выборка по массиву

Tags: массивы, php

Доброго времени суток.

Есть некий массив:

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "один"   => -100,
    "два"  => 100,
);
```

Причем известно, что ключи на английском языке - это служебная информация, а ключи на русском - это та информация, которая должна выводиться.

Вопрос: можно ли вывести значение так:

```
<p>"один"</p><p>"-100"</p>
<p>"два"</p><p>"100"</p>
```

при этом неизвестно, сколько будет ключей на английском языке, и какие символы будут использоваться, тоже неизвестно, но, скорее всего, они будут начинаться на знаке нижнее подчеркивание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пробегаем по массиву foreach смотрим ключ, если первая буква английская или нижнее подчеркивание - пропускаем, иначе выводим.

P.S. проверка букву регуляркой (preg_match)

Comment: думаю, самый удобный способ - использовать коды таблицы [ASCII](http://vbbook.ru/page/ascii-tablica-simvolov/), а также функции [ord()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ord.php) и [chr()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.chr.php)

Comment: Вот в этом то и вопрос понятно что примерно так 
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
$sub =//некое регулярное выражение
 if(preg_match($sub,$key))
  {}else{
    echo"<p>".$key."</p><p>".$value."</p>";}
}
но видимо я не правильно выразился как мне написать регулярное выражение учитывая что это все иностраные буквы и цифры + знак нижнего подчеркивания и как сейчас выяснилось ещё и слово "Цена" целивом.

Comment: @Sergalas, вы написали, что первая буква у служебной информации 100% либо английская, либо черта, ну так берете первую букву из слова и по регулярке a-zA-Z_, если проходит, знач. служебная, нет так нет)

Comment: Спасибо, меня именно подчеркивание чего-то выбивало из колеи.